# How to get the Magento Sync manager to update modules (sync) through CLI?

Tags: magento2, cli

In a Magento 2 system (2.0.9) I need to sync the Module manager to get the new bought modules from the Magento2 Market place. It just does not work! Syncing offers the "Spinning wheel" that it is busy loading and that's it. So nothing is loaded. How to get this done through the CLI?

Or how to get the modules from the Market Place as a file to upload them manually?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your cron jobs are set up and running correctly.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/prereq/prereq_cron.html

> To enable us to update or upgrade your system, you must configure two cron jobs. Each cron job should run every minute.
>
> The cron jobs schedule tasks for the Setup Wizard and for the updater application. These applications work together to install, update, and upgrade the Magento application and components.

The symptoms you describe are consistent with Magento's upgrade cron not being set up, or being set up but not running correctly. The official documentation linked above describes the proper cron setup.

If your crons are all set up, check if you have a file `var/.update_cronjob_status`, and if so, what it says. Any update cron errors will be detailed there. The most common issue is insufficient write permissions.

Comment: That file is not available. Since I am on a hosted environment I can not access through terminal and setup the cronjob. Is ther a other way to achieve this?

Comment: Well, your Magento installation is probably not set up correctly then. I don't know your hosting environment, but could you contact your host's support about the issue? If they won't let you do it yourself, I would think they should help.

Comment: contacting the host support is the last thing to do. They are not very eager to help. 
I am able to run: a php.file with:
system('php -f bin/magento cron:run');
Giving in return:
Ran jobs by schedule.
So could I also do something similar for getting the cronjob for the mudules /upgrade to work?

Comment: I did a file refresh and found out that the file var/.update_cronjob_status exist. It mentioned one prob with a file permission (a backup file from the old magento shop) so deleted that. And now the file gives: {
    "readiness_checks": {
        "file_permissions_verified": true
    },
    "last_timestamp": 1476112720,
    "current_timestamp": 1476117115
}
 
But it did not change much for the Component Manager it is still not Syncing.

Comment: Made some progress. Appeared that I can set the Cron Jobs through Direct Admin. Now the "Readiness Check". gives all green lights. I can see the log files created. But the Component Manager "Sync" still does not load? The log files are empty. So what's next?

Comment: Seems that the Crons are running. But the log -files are empty? Any ideas where to look and find out what's wrong here? How to solve this?

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: To test the cron job I made the systemsend a mail and it says:

Comment: [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]  
 exec function is disabled. 
cron:run [--group="..."] [--bootstrap="..."]

So can this be the cause that the syncing doesn't work?

Comment: That could be related. You would have to contact your host about that.

Comment: Ok seems that they fixed this error but still my syncing stays on loading. I found this in the file .setup_cronjob_status

Comment: "always_populate_raw_post_data": {
                    "message": "Your PHP Version is 5.5.31, but always_populate_raw_post_data = 0.\n \t        $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated from PHP 5.6 onwards and will be removed in PHP 7.0.\n \t        This will stop the installer from running.\n\t        Please open your php.ini file and set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1.\n \t        If you need more help please call your hosting provider.",
Is this indeed an error message or just in that file in case of an error?

Comment: Asked the provider to solve the always_populate_raw_post_data = now that error message is gone. But still not loading!! 
What can I do to find out where this is blocked?

Comment: Any other ideas how to trouble shoot this further? Could there be a problem with rights on certain directories which are blocking the syncing?

Comment: now got stuck on this error: 
get http://my_magento2.com/setup/index.php/componentGrid/sync 500 internal server error angular.min.js (line 77)  How to deal with this??